# Probability Distribution for Product of two Random Numbers?

Tags: probability-distributions

If I multiply two random numbers from 1 to 10 together I will get an outcome from 1 to 100. Over a large enough sample size the outcomes will tend to cluster closer to 1 than to 100 (only 21 of the 100 possible outcomes are greater than 50, for example).

- How would the probability distribution of the outcomes be described?
- Suppose that I have a percentage figure, say 60% in mind; how would I find the number below which I could expect 60% of all outcomes to fall? (For example - 79% of all outcomes fall below 50).

Please keep in mind that I am looking for a solution that is easily programmable (ie not reliant on graphs or tables etc).

Answer (score 2):

> How would the probability distribution of the outcomes be described?

You would describe it precisely using a [probability mass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function). This simply lists the probabilities of each outcome individually:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\rm{Pr}(X=1) &=& 0.01 \\
\rm{Pr}(X=2) &=& 0.02 \\
\rm{Pr}(X=3) &=& 0.02 \\
\rm{Pr}(X=4) &=& 0.03 \\
\ldots && \\
\rm{Pr}(X=100) &=& 0.01
\end{eqnarray*}$$

The sum of all the probabilities has to add up to one, of course.

$$\sum_{x=1}^{100}\rm{Pr}(X=x) = 1$$

[Descriptive statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_statistics) can also be used. E.g. a graphical description using a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram), left, or a [boxplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot), right.

[image]

Or, you can [quantitatively summarize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summary_statistics) the distribution. The median is 24, the mean is 30.25, the standard deviation (a measure of spread) is 23.94. The statistical term used for "Over a large enough sample size the outcomes will tend to cluster closer to 1 than to 100" is that the distribution is right-skewed, or colloquially, has a right tail (this can be expressed quantitatively using skew).

> Suppose that I have a percentage figure, say 60% in mind; how would I find the number below which I could expect 60% of all outcomes to fall? (For example - 79% of all outcomes fall below 50).

Mathematically, what you are doing here is using the [quantile function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function), $Q$. This is the inverse of the cumulative distribution function $F$, which is defined as follows:

$$F(x) = \rm{Pr}(X\le x)$$

So, $Q = F^{-1}$, e.g. to find the median $m$, we solve $\rm{Pr}(X\le m) = 0.5$.

> Please keep in mind that I am looking for a solution that is easily programmable (ie not reliant on graphs or tables etc).

For this particular problem, I would say the easiest solution is to list all the possible outcomes ($1\times 1, 1\times 2, 1\times 3 \ldots 10\times 10$), and sort the list. Then the $n^{\rm{th}}$ value in the list gives $\rm{Pr}(X\le n/100)$, because all outcomes are equally likely. In a language such as C, C++ or Java you could write a nested `for` loop to write the outcomes into an array and then use built-in functions to sort the array.

In a language like R, you can make use of built-in vector operations like so. The R code below confirms your assertion that "79% of all outcomes fall below 50".

```
> x=sort(outer(1:10,1:10))
> x[79]
[1] 49
> x[80]
[1] 50
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean the random variables to be independent. Then you should simply program a simulation. As an example, following yours, suppose ¤X¤ and ¤Y¤ are two independent random variables, each with a uniform distribution on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$. The do this in R:

```
repl <- 100000
X <- sample(1:10, repl, replace=TRUE)
Y <- sample(1:10, repl, replace=TRUE)
Z <- X*Y
hist(Z)
```

or you can do any other calculations you want with your sample $Z$
to describe its distribution.

Comment: rather than simulating, it is easier to get the actual distribution in this case. E.g., run `par(mfrow=c(1,2)); hist(Z,breaks=seq(0,100,by=2.5)); x=sort(outer(1:10,1:10)); hist(x,breaks=seq(0,100,by=2.5))`.